# Config variables available in rails environment file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, config, environment, initializer

I'm currently using an initializer to load a config.yml file into an AppConfig hash which offers access to variables for the environment. For production I am using environmental variables set on the server. I am using the following code to fallback to the config variable if the environmental variables are not set (i.e in development and test).

```
ENV['FACEBOOK_API_KEY'] || AppConfig['facebook_api_key']
```

My problem is that I need some of these variables to be available in the environment-specific file (development.rb/production.rb etc), but this file is loaded before the initialzers. How should I deal with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at the Rails guide for [Configuration Initialization Events](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#initialization-events). There are events that you can hook into when doing this kind of configuration.

In short you can have configuration for the environment done after initialisation with:

```
#config/environments/development.rb
YourApp::Application.configure do
  config.after_initialize do
    #do some configuration after all initialisers have run
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly what I needed. Its actually after_initialize NOT after_initializion btw.

Comment: Ha - thanks. I was thinking of spelling initialise US style and my fingers decided to type initialization instead.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a way you can create a two-tier structure like `database.yml` you could always define separate configurations for each environment in the same file, then reference the appropriate version:

```
ENV['FACEBOOK_API_KEY'] || AppConfig[Rails.env] && AppConfig[Rails.env]['facebook_api_key']
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's actually what I'm doing, only I'm not using a separate hash for the environment as I won't ever need to store config values for more than one at a time.